# Unable to process payouts: Invalid address length, expected 40 got 1 bytes

Tags: mining-pools

I [installed open ethereum pool](https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool) for mining Musicon, now pool found 3 blocks, but cant sent payments.
Getting error: Unable to process payouts: Invalid address length, expected 40 got 1 bytes

Comment: Did you give any address? 1 byte = 8 bits so it means 2 hexadecimal digits which is very low...